# Have image fit 100% width on mobile platforms

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile, css

so I am currently implementing a mobile version to my website and everything is fine except I want to be able make it so the image will fill 100% width of the screen whether the user tuns it horizontally or vertically. The image fits 100% like normal on any non-based mobile platform, but does not on a mobile device. Any suggestions?

I currently am using

```
.blog{
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #eeeeee;
    padding:10px;
    background:#ececec;
}
.blog-img{
    text-align:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px 0 5px 0;
}
```

I've also tried:

```
min-width:100%;
```

Comment: Did you using any framework for example Bootstrap v3.0.0?

Comment: No framework used for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The image fits 100% like normal on any non-based mobile platform, but does not on a mobile device.

It is not working as expected because you are giving the parent element `.blog-img` a width of `100%`.

You need to directly target the nested `img` descendant element and give it a width of `100%`:

```
.blog-img img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, setting a `min-width` of `100%` may be better in certain cases.

```
.blog-img img {
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

- Using `width: 100%` will stretch the `img` element to a width of `100%`.
- Using `max-width: 100%` will increase the width of the `img` element to the maximum total width of the `img` resource. In other words, this will prevent the `img` element from being stretched larger than it actually is.

Here is an minimal example highlighting the difference:

```html
<p>Using <code>max-width: 100%</code></p>
<img style="max-width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/50" />


<p>Using <code>width: 100%</code></p>
<img style="width: 100%;" src="http://placehold.it/50" />
```

Since you're optimizing your site for mobile browsers, be sure to set a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I can upload the css/html to JSfiddle

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks alot for the help, accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, add the image you want, as a background of a DIV or the document's BODY.

If you decide to go with a DIV, **width: 100%;**, **height: 100%;** and you can also include **z-index**, if you wish to go above or behind some content.

```
{
    background-image: url(http://arianapierce.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/simple-lights-twitter-background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I would also suggest you include viewport in your HTML, it makes the page much more stable.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <img src="/static/.." class="fit">

.fit {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

This keep image size for big screens and shrink it for small ones.

Comment: OP has not asked for keeping original image size on big screens, instead they want 100% width-fitting everywhere. not every browser has the default behavior of image expanding till max-width..

Comment: "fit 100% width on mobile platforms" doesn't mean everywhere.
I post most used case (at least I've looked for and apply this solution recently on my site)