# make image responsive in mobile

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I am trying to make a product page where I want the picture to scale depending on the screen, but I'm stuck and can't get on.

I have tried all the pages in here on the same issue, but just can't get it to work.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container4"><img src="../billeder/antennefor.jpg" width="797" height="576" alt=""/></div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```css
.container4{
    background-image:url(../billeder/antennefor.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #D54244;
    background-color:transparent;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%:
}
```

Comment: You have a fixed width for you image so it doesn't shrink with the page. Remove the width and height attribute for the img tag and add a css rule .container4 > img { width: 100% } This should ensure the image always fit to the width of the page.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77937488/548473

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are using HTML tag `width` and `height`, this is not good practice.

So remove those tags.

Instead of this:

```
<img src="../billeder/antennefor.jpg" width="797" height="576" alt=""/>
```

Have this

```
<img src="../billeder/antennefor.jpg" alt=""/>
```

and in your CSS you only need to have `max-width:100%`  applied to `img`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if is thaht, but you can test.

HTML:

```
<div class="container4">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container4 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/fabiovaz/pen/BKpwxX

Answer (score 0):

in your image element set the width in percent (%) and don't mind about the height.

this maybe help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using Bootstrap?

That's what I use to make my images responsive. all you have to do is include the Bootstrap CSS and then apply the "img-responsive" class to your images.

More info @ http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Comment: None of your input works, i'm sad to say, but I also forgot to say that the image is inside an iframe, in fact, all the content is taken from an iframe.